# How to perform code migration from TFS 2018 to Azure DevOps?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

We are trying to migrate code from TFS2018 to Azure DevOps. I am new to code migration from TFS to VSTS. I would like to know is there any tool for code migration?

I saw TFS-GIT utility. I am really not sure how much efficient this tool.

[GIT-TFS list remote repostiory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k5KB.jpg)

Comment: There is both a guidance document and tool available for this. You should start here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/devops/migrate/
Remarks: VSTS was renamed to Azure DevOps

Comment: I will not be able to use import option, since import exe is not supported for TFS 2018. It needs to be DevOpsServer2019.

Comment: Well, then you could upgrade your TFS 2018 to Azure DevOps Server 2019 and use the import after that.

Comment: Yeah, you only need to attach the TFS2018 DB to a (trial) 2019 server to perform the upgrade. It's usually just a couple of hours work. You can set the whole thing up on a temporary Azure machine. Cost would be very limited, as the machine only has to be up for the duration of the upgrade&import. We perform such upgrades regularly for customers.

Comment: we dont have control over infrastructure. We will not be able ot upgrade or make any changes to TFS server. Due to which we are forced look into other options

Comment: Can you better explain what you are trying to accomplish? It sounds like you want to convert from TFVC to Git and at the same time move from TFS to Azure DevOps. Do you just want sources? Or also builds? Workitems? Test cases? Packages?

Comment: @Guru, I've done upgrades on my laptop prior to migration. All you need is a Windows 10 Pro laptop with a load of memory and a big SSD. That and a complete set of backup files.

Comment: 1. We are trying to migrate from TFS to VSTS                                                                          2. We will not be able to use microsoft suggested import option                                    3. we would need to migrate code,changeset, workitems to VSTS                            4. I am really not sure which tool to go with for above task.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it through OpsHub tool: [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility)

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to either upgrade your on-premise server to Azure DevOps Server 2019 or the latest Team Foundation Server 2018 update pack that's supported by the migration tool.

You can perform this upgrade on a clone instance of your existing server, so it won't break or change your existing machine or database in case anything goes wrong.

We regularly perform these types of migrations and we generally use a temporary Azure Virtual Machine. We install SQL Server on it, we restore the backup of the on-premise server, we install the desired TFS application tier version on it. If the Azure machine is joined to your domain, then that's all you need to start the import into Azure DevOps. If the machine isn't domain joined, be sure to turn off the AD Sync job as part of the migration. [My colleague Jasper has a couple of scripts to fix that for you](https://github.com/JasperGilhuis/AzureDevOpsMigration/blob/master/Migration/00-Disable-ADSync.ps1).

---

Alternate options. In my opinion there aren't any. At least not good ones. There is a whole set of tools that an migrate parts of TFS to Azure DevOps, tools like [OpsHub](https://www.opshub.com/), [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs), [git-tf](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30474), [Migration Tools for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration). None offer a complete migration, some do work items, some sources, some builds, but none of these offer a complete migration.

All of these also have the issue that they reset metadata such as Commit/Approval dates, work item IDs. Which will impact retention jobs, history and other things you may care about.

Comment: @jessehouwing- I am trying to achieve it using git-tfs. I am not able to clone from TFS in first place.                                                                                                                                        `code` git-tfs clone http://xxx.xx.net/tfs/xx-xx $/Solutions/Emerging Technologies/Test xx/Code And Unit Testing/Source/XX.123                                         "xx.123" is project name

Comment: Looks like you're missing quotes around the server path.

Comment: And must use `git tfs` instead of `git-tfs`.

Comment: jessehowing- do i need to give complete path for the repository till my branch. when i run following list-Remote-branches command                                                                 I could see branch path is too long   example :                $/Solutions/EmergingTechnologies/xx/CodeAndUnitTesting/Source/XX.123

Comment: Just ProjectName/Branch name would suffice

Comment: Because TFVC can have multiple branch roots in a single repository, you need to give a branch root to create a Git repo. In Git the repo root and the branch root are the same. So you may need to export to multiple repositories. Hard to tell with the limited information you shared.